# Is there a issue for the folder/directory name to be module name in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module, module-info

Quoting from [this source](https://labs.consol.de/development/2017/02/13/getting-started-with-java9-modules.html), it mentions that

> The name of the directory containing a module’s sources should be
>   equal to the name of the module, e.g. for de.consol.devday.service

Is this a good recommendation consider that folder name is subjected to character limitation of the operating system (eg 255 as the maximum length for Windows ) and that could constraint on how we name the folder and module?

Hoping that someone from Java core team can give insight on this and provide a recommendation.

Quoting another example from [here](http://www.baeldung.com/project-jigsaw-java-modularity):-
[image]

**The module name follow the folder name and folder name is constraint by 255 character limit, is that scalable?**

It may be that in actual code, most likely the folder name may not reach that limit, however such limitation should be mentioned in official Java doc to consider such way ( maybe it has ? or someone can point to that if so ?)

thank

Answer (score 2):

Though I am not from the java core team as you might expect but [The State of the Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/) reads it as this-

> A module declaration is compiled, by convention, into a file named
>   module-info.class, *placed similarly in the class-file output
>   directory*.

The character limitation of the operating system could constraint on how we name the folder and module but ideally, IMHO even 255 characters are more than sufficient to dictate any good naming convention and design.

---

Just to add to it, the `module-info.java` declaration is similar(module vs package) to the existing [`package-info.java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599058/eclipse-juno-what-is-the-use-of-package-info-java?noredirect=1&lq=1) declaration except for the fact that the latter was used only for documentation purposes.

Comment: How do we structure the  source code to conform to modular way ?

Further  reading on http://www.baeldung.com/project-jigsaw-java-modularity also follow the same practice as what I have raised.

Does IDE like Intellij work that way too ?

Comment: To confirm to the modular way, you must include the class named `module-info.java` which provides its module declaration,

Comment: I understand that the module-info.java is essential.

But the question is what is the recommended way to layout the modular project structure in term of physical source layout



`

Comment: The recommended way is as suggested in both the linked articles by you, as well as the linked document by me. The `module-info.java` of module `com.foo.bar` to be defined within `com.foo.bar` directory.

Comment: the question is how scalable this way is when directory is constraint by the folder name limitation ? 

what if I have come to a point where the whole  name exceed 255 characters ?

The point I raising is not so much of just simply following the suggested way but thinking further along the line whether such way is scalable as mention in the post :} .

If there is indeed folder & module name sync could be a issue, why are those sites still suggest those way ?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what scalability issues you see with the naming conventions and believe the syntax of module-info must have been debated in the mailing lists as well, just not able to find one to share with you for now.

Comment: Why would we expect you to be from the java core team?

Answer (score 2):

Naming modules as the top package is a should, not a must. See for example JSL 6.1.

> The name of a module should correspond to the name of its principal
>   exported package. If a module does not have such a package, or if for
>   legacy reasons it must have a name that does not correspond to one of
>   its exported packages, then its name should still start with the
>   reversed form of an Internet domain with which its author is
>   associated.

I would consider Windows 7 a legacy reason (MAX_PATH = 260 characters). Workaround: use `subst` to assign a drive letter to a folder or update to Windows 10, which has an opt-in of 32,767 characters.

A package name with 260 characters rendered in Monaco 13 exceeds the width of my 23'' monitor by 20 characters. It’s common sense that I shouldn’t have to scroll horizontally to read a module name. Note that in the JDK 9 (+20,000 classes) the longest module name is 32 characters:

```
for file in $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9)/jmods/*; do echo -n `basename "$file"` | wc -m; done
```

Oracle doesn’t even follow the rules. If you want to import `java.util.logging.Logger` you import `java.logging`, not `java.util.logging`. And no, java.logging it’s not the main package, it is java.util.logging:

```
$ cd $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 9)/jmods/
$ jar -tf java.logging.jmod 
classes/module-info.class
classes/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.class
classes/java/util/logging/ErrorManager.class
classes/java/util/logging/FileHandler$1.class
classes/java/util/logging/FileHandler$InitializationErrorManager.class
...
```

Answer (score 1):

While most discussion here focuses on the module name, let me add that the directory layout as shown in the question is mandatory only for what [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) calls *multi-module mode*. Build tools and IDEs are free to support different directory layouts. Note how [JLS 7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3) delegates some decisions to the "host system":

> The  host  system  may  determine  that  an  observable  ordinary  compilation  unit
>   is associated with a module chosen by the host system ...

Here, every tool used for driving modular compilation can be considered a host system.

With this, it should be no problem to give the folder containing sources for a module any useful, short name you like.