# Javadoc API as part of larger documentation

Tags: java, javadoc

One of the nice things about sphinx and python is the relatively simple coupling between API documentation and explanatory documentation in markdown using chapters and sections that give the background and examples. Is there a way to do this in Java using javadoc, sphinx or some other library that has general community traction?

Comment: Isn't that what javadoc is for? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: What you're asking for seems to be exactly what Javadoc does already (though instead of Markdown it uses Javadoc taglets and HTML elements).

Comment: It is not obvious this is what javadoc does. Most online descriptions of javadoc have "API" in the sentence. I'm not as experienced with javadoc, but I don't see examples that have a readthedocs like exposition and their own structure, based for instance on use cases and hints and not on package structure.  @Ankit Kumar has a suggestion below shows sphinx can do the job even for Java, so +1 at least from me. However sphinx adds baggage for a Java project so if it can all be done in javadoc I would probably accept that answer.

Comment: @EliS You can provide package level documentation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599058/eclipse-juno-what-is-the-use-of-package-info-java. There you can write documentation on how to use the package you are writing.

Comment: You can do pretty much anything you want with Javadoc. It can have links to external sources, or links to other embedded HTML pages (see VGR's answer). You can also put examples in Javadoc with `<pre><code>` HTML elements, or `{@code}` and, in more recent versions, `{@snippet}` taglets. You can explain the purpose of the API and some reasons for using it. You can use package-level or even module-level Javadoc for more general documentation. Whether any of this is done depends on how much effort is put into the it; even in the standard library, not everything has the same level of documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javadoc absolutely does support this.

Internal documentation can be included in the special subdirectory `doc-files` under any package.  The javadoc tool will always copy doc-files subdirectories into generated documentation file trees, making them stable sources to which class (and package) javadoc can link using relative paths.  All javadoc content is HTML, so ordinary `<a href="…">` elements are sufficient.

Examples:

- The [java.awt package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/package-summary.html) documentation links to in-depth Focus Subsystem documentation and in-depth modality documentation, both included in Java SE in a doc-files subdirectory.
- The [javax.imageio package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) documentation links to full descriptions of metatadata for the image formats its supports, all located in a doc-files subdirectory.
- Many security classes’ documentation will link to a table of standard algorithm names. For example, [KeyStore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html) links to a table of standard keystore types, with descriptions of each.  This document is part of the Java SE javadocs.

External links can be placed in `@see` or `@spec` tags, like this:

```
/**
 * This is a description of a package or class or class member.
 *
 * @see <a href="https://example.com/docs/concepts/">General concepts explanation</a>
 * @spec https://example.com/standard/myprotocol/ My protocol specification
 */
```

- The [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) class contains an external link to the IEEE floating point standard.
- The [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) documentation uses `@spec` to refer to language tag specifications.
- The [java.util.zip package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) documentation links to full specifications related to zip and gzip compression.

If you’re looking for tutorials and examples, many Swing classes have such links.  For example:

- The [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html) documentation’s first paragraph links to the “How to Use Tables” section of the Java tutorial.
- The [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) documentation’s first paragraph links to the “How to Use File Choosers” section of the Java tutorial.

There are many more links to in-depth documentation in Java SE.  The above ones are just some that I remembered off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate Javadoc Links:
Link to your Javadoc-generated API documentation within your explanatory documentation using intersphinx references. For example:

```
:java:package:: com.example
:java:module:: com.example.mymodule
:java:method:: MyClass.myMethod(param1, param2)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this comment. I accepted the answer from @VGR because it is great set of examples that better explains the boundaries of javadoc. However, sphinx is still a much more powerful tool and when I need that I'll be re-visiting your answer.